# Need to define a 'search' function for my dictionary

Tags: python

I need to define a search function for my code that searches for letters within my dictionary. I am only missing the actual 'search' loop and code. Many lines of code have been left out for ease of reading.

```
while True:
  option = get_option()
  ...
  elif (option == "S"):
    search(users)
  ...
users = {}

def add(users):
  student_number = input('Enter student number: ')
  family_name = input("Enter family name: ")
  first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
  phone_number = input('Enter phone number: ')

  single_info = {"student_number": student_number, "family_name": family_name, "first_name": first_name, "phone_number": phone_number}

  users[student_number] = single_info
  print("Record is added.")
...
family_name = input("Enter family name: ")
first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
```

```
#              STN            Name                          Phone          
1              0123456        John Smith                    111222         
2              1111111        Mary Lee                      001122         
3              2222222        Hoa Zhang                     334455 
2              7676767        Milka Sjanovic                012012
```

This is the dictionary with the inputs, I require a search function to search for names within this.

expected output is

```
Search record by name.
Enter text to search: Mi
Search found 2 records.

#           STN             Name              Phone
1           0123456         John Smith        111222
2           7676767         Milka Sjanovic    012012
```

Comment: How is this a dictionary? I see a table

Comment: Can you add the structure of the dictionary?

Comment: Either way, the whole point of using a dictionary is that you *don't* have to search. If you do then you are using the wrong elements as keys

Comment: It's not a dictionary, its dictionaries nested in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse your dictionary using a comprehension to build a result set:

```
text = input("Enter text to search:").lower()
result = [ s for s in users.values() if text in (s["family_name"]+" "+s["first_name"]).lower() ]
print(f"Search found {len(result)} records")
for i,s in enumerate(result):
   print(i+1,s["student_number"],s["first_name"],s["family_name"],s["phone_number"])
```

*note: Given that you provided no usable test data, I just typed this in the answer box.  You will need to fix any typos, and add formatting yourself*

You could also separate the criteria definition from the search process like this:

```
criteria = lambda s:any(text in s[n].lower() for n in ["family_name","first_name"]) 
result   = list(filter(criteria,users.values()))
```

This will give you more flexibility and the ability to easily create searches on other fields.  For example, searching in any field:

```
criteria = lambda s: text in " ".join(s.values()).lower()
result   = list(filter(criteria,users.values()))
```